# How to decide a value of learning rate for Stochastic Gradient Descent?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, stochastic-processes, nonlinear-optimization

I'd like to know how to decide a value of learning rate for Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD), such as $\eta$ on the following parameter update iteration equation,

$w_{i+1} = w_i + -\eta \nabla E_n(w_i)$

With the SGD, it is better that $\eta$ is proportional to $t^{-1}$ ($t$ means times of iteration), according to ["Large-Scale Machine Learning with Stochastic Gradient Descent" by Leon Bottou](http://leon.bottou.org/publications/pdf/compstat-2010.pdf).

However, I feel that it is too strong assumption because the convergence may be strongly depend on the $t^{-1}$ rather than the gradient "$\nabla E_n(w_i)$" itself.

I would appreciate it if anyone gives me some advice.

Comment: The best advice would be to ask the question on Cross Validated.  However,  if your question is statistical, rather than being about rate of convergence, then I don't understand why CV wouldn't be what you want.

Comment: Thank you aginensky!
I also think CV is the best way to decide the parameter, however CV is just procedure for verifying the value of the parameter after trial. I’d like to know whether there is a logical method to decide the parameter. (e.g. how to set a initial value of the parameter)

Comment: I think the article you cite has as much information as anything.  I don't know of any theoretical explanations for learning rate that would explain how to optimally choose a specific rate.  The article you cite has some comments.  Again, I suggest putting the question on cross validated.  That is where there is an audience capable of giving a good answer to your question.